# How to find entity with any value of argument

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring JPA` with `hibernate` and have an entity with a lot of properties, let's say it has five; as illustrated below:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity{
 Object properties1;
 Object properties2;
 Object properties3;
 Object properties4;
 Object properties5;
}
```

Spring provides a very nice feature; it generates JPQL query based on method name in the repository. For example:

```
List<MyEntity> findByProperties3(Object properties3);
```

In my situation, users have an html form to search for a `MyEntity`. This html form has five fields respectively which correspond to the five properties on the `MyEntity` class. User also can leave any field empty so that the search will include all values of this property in the query.

I have idea of how to implement that but it would break away from the Spring convenience methods and need a lot of coding. My idea is to create a method on the repository interface for all possibilities: user leaving all field empty, filling one field, two fields, etc; up to five fields. Unfortunately, that means that there would be:

[image]

possibilities. How can I avoid this path? Ideally, I would create just one method:

```
List<MyEntity> findByProperties1andProperties2andProperties3andProperties4andProperties5(Object p1,Object p2,Object p3,Object p4,Object p5)
```

But, if some of the `pX`s are null, then Spring JPA will explicitly find `MyEntity`s with `propertiesX` equal to null, as opposed to all possible values of, say, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `null`.

**===========EDIT===============**

I am still hoping to get an answer from someone about a `Spring JPA` solution, but I've used `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` in the mean time for my solution.